# Why are two requests from different IPs recorded in my logs sometimes when I load a page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, authorization

My logs show unauthorized requests for URLs that I loaded on the backend. It seems quite odd to me:

```
app[web.1] Started GET "/en/app_logs/853669" for 174.227.2.90 at 2018-06-03 19:39:16 +0000
app[web.1] Processing by AppLogsController#show as HTML
app[web.1]   Parameters: {"locale"=>"en", "id"=>"853669"}
app[web.1] ----------------
app[web.1] The params: {"controller"=>"app_logs", "action"=>"show", "locale"=>"en", "id"=>"853669"}
app[web.1] ----------------
app[web.1] The user: #<User:0x00005612eed357f0>
app[web.1] ----------------

...

app[web.1] Started GET "/en/app_logs/853669" for 66.249.92.28 at 2018-06-03 19:39:18 +0000
app[web.1] Processing by AppLogsController#show as */*
app[web.1]   Parameters: {"locale"=>"en", "id"=>"853669"}
app[web.1] ----------------
app[web.1] The params: {"controller"=>"app_logs", "action"=>"show", "locale"=>"en", "id"=>"853669"}
app[web.1] ----------------
app[web.1] The user:
app[web.1] ----------------
app[web.1] #<AuthorizeRequest::NotAuthorized: We're sorry, but you don't seem to have access to app_logs/show. Do you need to sign in?  >
```

I recently re-wrote my authorization logic after realizing that declarative authorization was no longer maintained. So I can't tell if it's my code, or not.

The authorization happens in

```
before_action :authorize_access!
```

The stack is heroku with rails 5.2, and I'm using a hotspot from a samsung galaxy android.

I'm having trouble understanding what's going on, and can't tell if it's something routine, or something malicious. I don't know if I'm hacked or what is going on. I'd like to know if it's my authorization code, a result of some weird think in rails I don't know about, an affect of running on a hot spot, or some malicious code somewhere trying to piggyback on my requests. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have any browser plugins that might be trying to fetch the page?

Comment: Are you using some kind of caching service that has it's own IP? e.g. Memcached or Redis on AWS?

Comment: This ip (66.249.92.28) and another that shows in my logs (66.249.92.129) seem to be located at Google in Mountain View. Could this be some kind of analytics tool? Or an add tool? I have both running on my site.